# Using OpenCV DNN module with OpenBlas

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, openblas, dotnetnuke

I am trying to run Faster-RCNN object detector in an C++ OpenCV project.

As far as I know (https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/490) some time ago there were some problems with the computational time in the DNN module.

Some people found that Gemm method was the bottleneck and the solution was to use the MKL or OpenBlas implementation of it. (https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/86342522b0eb2b16fa851c020cc4e0fef4e010b7/modules/dnn/src/layers/op_blas.cpp#L100)

It is said that new releases of OpenCV have fixed this issue and computational time is almost the same as the Caffe implementation.

I have compile the latest GitHub version of OpenCV for C++ in Ubuntu 16.04 with the following information:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.0-pre =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/alex/Documents/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-04-19T11:12:11Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.13.0-38-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.5.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (2 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (9 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt /home/alex/Halide/build/lib/libHalide.so
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv dnn_modern hdf java matlab ovis python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.30)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.48.2)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.6)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.4)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
           at:                   /home/alex/Documents/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
              at:                /home/alex/Documents/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_lnx
    Lapack:                      YES (/usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/lib/libcblas.so /usr/lib/libatlas.so)
    Halide:                      YES (/home/alex/Halide/build/lib/libHalide.so /home/alex/Halide/build/include)
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/alex/Documents/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can check my OpenCV has been compiled with OpenBlas (Laplack) support, however and now comes my question, I do not know if in my code I have to specify that I want to run DNN net.forward method with OpenBlas or is done by default.

Sample of my code:

```
    double kInpWidth = 800;
    double kInpHeight = 600;

    // Resize Image
    Mat img = Camera.ActualFrame;
    cv::resize(img, img, Size(kInpWidth, kInpHeight));

    // Convert image to blob for the net
    Mat blob = blobFromImage(img, 1.0, Size(), Scalar(102.9801, 115.9465, 122.7717), false, false);
    Mat imInfo = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << img.rows, img.cols, 1.6f);

    // Pass data through the net
    net.setInput(blob, "data");
    net.setInput(imInfo, "im_info");

    // Net Forward
    Mat detections = net.forward();
    const float* data = (float*)detections.data;
```

I am having computational times of 25 seconds/frame which is not what I expected even running the Faster-RCNN in CPU mode.

Has someone use it with relativly lower computational times? How can I check that Gemm function is computed by OpenBlas?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04, OpenBLAS is not correctly detected with OpenCV (see this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9953)). I have installed instead Intel MKL. Anyway, 25 sec / frame seems too high. I use MobileNet SSD and I get around 80 ms / frame in average. You can find some benchmark [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/DNN-Efficiency), [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10608), [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11255) and [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10805).

Comment: You can find [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.cpp) a sample for DNN object detection with proper timing and bounding box display. If you want to try Intel MKL, you can download it [here](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/forms/?productid=2558&licensetype=2). Then, not sure but I think that you would need to pass to CMake: `-DMKL_ROOT_DIR=/opt/intel/mkl` or something like that.

Comment: Efficiency of object detection networks directly depends on input image resolution. Can you specify `kInpWidth` and `kInpHeight` values?

Comment: I have updated the code sample with `kInpWidth` and `kInpHeight` values

Comment: Once I have installed Intel MKL and compiled OpenCV with it should I change something in the code to enable its use?